# Override core - reset password file in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I need to send success email for after resetting password in laravel-5.4

I write code like this :

File path :  `mylaravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php`

Mycode :

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);

    $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

    $user->save();

$mail_data = array('name' => $user->first_name);

    Mail::send('mails.forgotpassword', $mail_data, function ($message) use($user) {
          $message->from(Config::get('globalvars.CONTACT_EMAIL'), 'Its Your Skills');
          $message->to($user->email);
          $message->subject('Forgot Password regarding');
    });

    event(new PasswordReset($user));

    $this->guard()->login($user);
}
```

i writed that mail code , This one working fine . but for updating composer that code will automatically delete. so i need to know how to doo this action in mylaravel/app folder. any help?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can not make change in any core file for that you have to make controller in your `app/html/comtrollers/auth` and then make same function as given in core file and override that function and change the functionality according that.

but do not try to make change in core file as you said in your question when ever change in composer and update laravel with newer version make trouble for you.

May i hope this helps you.

Comment: check this file-path which i mentioned - because in core they are using traits that's why am struggling.